# Async client side XSLT

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xslt, xmlhttprequest

I've followed the instructions over at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp) for client side XSLT and it's working fine. It however gives the warning that synchronous requests are deprecated.
I've searched for quite a while and found some code, tried it and failed miserably. So my question is: how should the w3schools example be modified for the requests to be async?

Edit: Martin Honnen's comment has a solution that works perfectly, I consider my question answered.

Comment: w3schools is quite a poor resource in most cases, and the example code you linked is no exception. Inline handlers, implicitly creating global variables all over the place, `ActiveXObject`...

Comment: You can use asynchronous requests with `XMLHttpRequest` and perhaps also exploit `Promise`s to make sure you have both the  XML input and the XSLT loaded, see https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/blob/master/xslt/arcor-archive/2016/test2016081501.html for an example.

Comment: Brilliant Martin! That works perfectly, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 2):

You might like to look at Saxon-JS which offers a lot more capability than the XSLT 1.0 engines built into the browsers:

- it supports XSLT 3.0 rather than 1.0 (giving you support for regular expressions, grouping, date/time handling, JSON support, etc etc)
- it allows you to handle user interaction from within the stylesheet
- it allows you to issue asyncronous HTTP requests from within the stylesheet
- it offers a much simpler API: you can do your example as

JS code:

```
 SaxonJS.transform({
      "stylesheetLocation" : "cdcatalog.xsl",
      "sourceLocation"     : "cdcatalog.xml"})
```

Disclaimer: this is my company's product.

Further information at http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml

(The browsers give a 'synchronous access' warning when loading Saxon-JS, as it happens, but you can ignore it because the synchronous access is there only to support the document() function which you should ideally not be using.)